# Is it possible to change nested object properties with this syntax

Tags: javascript

Say you have this object:

```
myObj = { foo: { bar : 123, baz: 456 } };
```

To edit the value of bar you can do this:

```
myObj['foo']['bar'] = 789
```

But what if you have a method somewhere that changes specific object properties like this:

```
myObj[key] = value
```

If you need to use that and you want to edit `bar` in the `myObj` object, is it possible with that code?

I tried:

```
myObj["foo"."bar"] = 789;
myObj["foo"["bar"]] = 789;
```

But it doesn't work. Is it possible at all to do?

Answer (score 0):

Pure JavaScript doesn't allow you to access nested properties with a simple string.

An alterative can be i.e. lodash:

```
_.get(myObj, 'foo.bar'); // 123

_.set(myObj, 'foo.bar', 789);
```

Comment: If `_` can do it, there's also a "pure Javascript" way to do it (albeit using more code)…

Comment: @deceze I assue we're talking about the simplest solutions here.

Comment: Including an additional library is not necessarily the simplest solution…

Comment: Thanks Hsz, but indeed I was hoping for a pure Javascript way, lodash isn't an option in the project unfortunately.